# Will computers always behave in an expected way, given constant electrical input?

Tags: computer-architecture, nondeterminism, history

For the purposes of this question, please forget about computers being unable to perform as expected due to excess workloads, exceeded capacities, or general bad hardware/devious software (e.g. a calculator programmed . I'm only concerned with a perfectly "healthy" computer's not what was expected of it.

What are some scenarios in which a computer did *not* behave as expected, even though it received constant electrical input and was, for all intents and purposes, "on"?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really computer _science_ or even that it's really answerable. Essentially, you're saying, "Excluding almost every conceivable thing that could make a computer malfunction, what could make a computer malfunction?" The only thing I can think of that you've forgotten to exclude is ionizing radiation causing unintended electrical signals.

Comment: I see what you mean. I suppose, barring anything negative impacting the computer's state, it will *always* perform the way it was programmed since it's a logical machine. Seems a bit obvious now that you've said it :)

Comment: Do you know where the term "bug" comes from?

Comment: I agree: this question is about how to make electronics fail. This is a matter for [electronics.SE], not [cs.SE].